# How do you filter mathematically calculated data in SQL?

Tags: sql, logic, arithmetic-expressions

This is probably easier than I think it is, but I am stumped. I wrote the following query which sums up all the purchases made by a customer at a particular store, as well as the total amount of returns made by the same customer at the same store, and lastly, stores the result of subtracting total returns from total purchases in a calculated column called TOTAL_SPENT. Here is my query:

```
SELECT Account_Id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Purchase' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_PURCHASED,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Return' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_RETURNED,
  (TOTAL_PURCHASED - TOTAL_RETURNED) AS TOTAL_SPENT
FROM Transactions_Table
WHERE Store = 'Store XYZ'
GROUP BY Account_Id
ORDER BY TOTAL_SPENT DESC
```

My problem is that this query returns hundreds of thousands of records, but I only care about approximately 10% of the data that's returned. So, say you only want to see data returned where TOTAL_SPENT >= 500.00. But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do this! *hanging head in shame*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, the `WHERE` clause is processed *before* the `SELECT` clause.  So, when SQL begins filtering the rows from your table that are relevent to your query, it doesn't yet *know* about the column `TOTAL_SPENT`.

There's a few ways to fix that.

**1)** Repeat the expressions in your `WHERE` clause, rather than referring to a column name in your `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT Account_Id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Purchase' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_PURCHASED,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Return' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_RETURNED,
  (TOTAL_PURCHASED - TOTAL_RETURNED) AS TOTAL_SPENT
FROM Transactions_Table
WHERE Store = 'Store XYZ'
GROUP BY Account_Id
ORDER BY 
  (SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Purchase' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Return' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END)) DESC
```

**Note:** If you're looking to find *groups* with a `TOTAL_SPENT` above 500, use the `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`.

**2)** Use a view.  Remove your `WHERE` clause and create a `VIEW` with your query.  Then, select from that *view* and add your `WHERE` clause.

```
CREATE VIEW Whatever AS
   SELECT Account_Id,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Purchase' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS    TOTAL_PURCHASED,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Return' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_RETURNED,
      (TOTAL_PURCHASED - TOTAL_RETURNED) AS TOTAL_SPENT
   FROM Transactions_Table
   GROUP BY Account_Id;

SELECT * From Whatever WHERE TOTAL_SPENT >= 500
```

**3)** Use a nested SELECT:

```
select * from (
  SELECT
    Account_Id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Purchase' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_PURCHASED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Return' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_RETURNED,
    (TOTAL_PURCHASED - TOTAL_RETURNED) AS TOTAL_SPENT
  FROM Transactions_Table
  WHERE Store = 'Store XYZ'
  GROUP BY Account_Id
) where TOTAL_SPENT > 500 ORDER BY TOTAL_SPENT DESC;
```

**4)** If your database supports it, use a CTE:

```
WITH MyQuery AS (
  SELECT
    Account_Id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Purchase' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_PURCHASED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'Return' THEN Transaction_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_RETURNED,
    (TOTAL_PURCHASED - TOTAL_RETURNED) AS TOTAL_SPENT
  FROM Transactions_Table
  WHERE Store = 'Store XYZ'
  GROUP BY Account_Id
)
SELECT * FROM MyQuery WHERE TOTAL_SPENT > 500 ORDER BY TOTAL_SPENT DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I tried creating a view, as you suggested, but unfortunately, I was not given an access level high enough to create view. I tried the nested select next and it gave me the exact results I was looking for.